# Where can I find the openxmlformats math schema used in MS Word?

Tags: math, ms-word, schema

I need to extract equations from a Word file. I have unzipped the docx and opened the document.xml, which lists a large number of schemas. But I have failed to find the schema for the math objects embedded in Word. The schemas.openxmlformats.org server is not found, and a search for the URI or parts of it does not give any results. Does anyone know where the schemas can be found ?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries with different search terms and checking some articles on Wikipedia I found the schemas at https://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/officeopenxml/2006/